# how to assign async firebase data to react initial state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm working on app like tinder to practice my skills on react native. I am having trouble with making conditional rendering from firebase backend.

Below is my code.

```
class CardsScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  users: [
    { name: "chris", gender: "male", interestedIn: "women" },
    { name: "jane", gender: "female", interestedIn: "men" },
    { name: "fred", gender: "male", interestedIn: "women" },
    { name: "vanessa", gender: "female", interestedIn: "men" }
  ],
  data: {}
};
this.usersRef = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("users/" + this.props.currentUser.uid);
this.likedRef = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("users/" + this.props.currentUser.uid + "/likes");
}

componentDidMount() {
this.listenUserInterest();
}

 listenUserInterest = () => {
this.usersRef.on("value", snapshot => {
  let gender = snapshot.val().gender;
  this.setState({ currentGender: gender });
  console.log(gender);
});
};

handleYup = card => {
const user = this.props.currentUser.uid;
if (user) {
  const newItem = {
    name: card.name,
    gender: card.gender,
    interestedIn: card.interestedIn
  };
  this.likedRef.push().update(newItem);
}
console.log(`Yup for ${card.name}`);
};

handleNope(card) {
console.log(`Nope for ${card.text}`);
}

renderNoMoreCards() {
return (
  <View>
    <Text style={styles.noMoreCardsText}>No more cards</Text>
  </View>
);
}

render() {
return (
  <SwipeCards
    cards={this.state.users}
    renderCard={cardData => <User {...cardData} />}
    renderNoMoreCards={this.renderNoMoreCards}
    handleYup={this.handleYup}
    handleNope={this.handleNope}
    hasMaybeAction
    source={{ uri: this.state.image }}
  />
  );
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
currentUser: state.user.currentUser
};
}
```

until now I made a signup based on interest and everything goes well. I put some static data to render cards based on their gender. Here is the part i am stuck. I just can't figure out how to get data and make conditional rendering based on gender from firebase. If I am interested in women I want to render only female cards. What should be the approach? i tried using async await but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning data to swipe cards, filter data there only.

like this,

```
<SwipeCards
    cards={this.state.users.filter(item=>item.gender == this.state.currentGender)} //this.state.currentGender contains current gender which can be any variable not necessary to be state
    renderCard={cardData => <User {...cardData} />}
    renderNoMoreCards={this.renderNoMoreCards}
    handleYup={this.handleYup}
    handleNope={this.handleNope}
    hasMaybeAction
    source={{ uri: this.state.image }}
  />
```

store current gender in state or variable

Answer (score 0):

For conditional rendering you can use something like this inside the render method:
{this.state.gender=='F'?[ //view ]:[ //view ] }
but I guess in your case you need to first, separate the list gender wise, and then show the list, that's better approach rather than conditional rendering

Comment: yes that could be a good approach but i need to make the filter from single array. For now to make things work i have static data. but later i will have to make this from firebase backend with single array without any static data

Comment: A simple solution to separating the list would be:
You retrieve the data in ComponentWillMount function
in the response, filter the list, make a new list, and set that list to a state list
pass that list to the SwipeList.
If you don't want to make a separate list,
You can use conditional rendering.

Comment: but the problem is, i can't assign the currentuser gender to state. your approach would make it simpler but first i need to get the gender for the user before i mount the component. i tried to put everything to redux store and use thunk but this time i can't reach the currentuser inside the action creator

Comment: solved my problem by putting the currentgender into redux. just needed to make some adjustments to reach on firebase database but finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

but i can only get the data from firebase with this function. if i put gender instead of interestedIn it will give me the gender. but how can i put this in a state or variable. its only available in the function?

```
listenUserInterest = card => {
this.usersRef.on("value", snapshot => {
let interestedIn = snapshot.val().interestedIn;
this.setState({ data: interestedIn });
console.log(interestedIn)// this gives interested in data
});
};
```